# Still having two Firebase users for the same account after linking Anonymous user with google signIn

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am working on an Android application and using Firebase Authentication to manage users.
I am creating an Anonymous account for all new users allowing them to walk throw the application freely. However, at some point, I will ask the user to actually sign in using Google sign in (for now) and of course, I am linking the anonymous credentials with google account.

Here is the code (Android-Java):

```
GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions);
    Intent signInIntent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, SIGN_IN_GOOGLE_ARC);
```

And here is the linking:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case SIGN_IN_GOOGLE_ARC:
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
                AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account != null ? account.getIdToken() : null, null);
                firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(authCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                //Do something
                            }
                        });
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

The code is working fine and the accounts are being linked. What's bothering me is that in the Firebase console I can still find the two users separated as you can see in the image:
[image: Firebase Users]

I have already tried to delete the anonymous user before and after passing the credentials but it obviously didn't work and I ended up deleting both of them because they are basically the same user.
Is there any way I can just delete the anonymous account after being linked?

Comment: The users have different `uid`. They don't appear to be the same.